# Modify answer on PHP based on JavaScript JSON response

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to write some text on the screen, but the text will change according to weather and condition (description). I'm working on this codepen.

```js
var weatherData = {
  city: document.querySelector ("#city"),
  weather: document.querySelector ("#weather"),
  temperature: document.querySelector("#temperature"),
  temperatureValue: 0,
  units: "°C"
  
};

function roundTemperature(temperature){
            temperature = temperature.toFixed(1);
            return temperature;
        }

function switchUnits (){
  
  if (weatherData.units == "°C") {
    weatherData.temperatureValue = roundTemperature(weatherData.temperatureValue * 9/5 + 32);
    weatherData.units = "°F";
  
} else {
  weatherData.temperatureValue = roundTemperature ((weatherData.temperatureValue -32) * 5/9);
    weatherData.units = "°C";  
}

  weatherData.temperature.innerHTML = weatherData.temperatureValue + weatherData.units + " ";
}


function getLocationAndWeather(){
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

      console.log(response);
      var position = {
        latitude: response.latitude,
        longitude: response.longitude
      };
      var cityName = response.city;

      var weatherSimpleDescription = response.weather.simple;
      var weatherDescription = translateDescription(response.weather.description);
      var weatherTemperature = roundTemperature(response.weather.temperature);

      weatherData.temperatureValue = weatherTemperature;

      loadBackground(position.latitude, position.longitude, weatherSimpleDescription);
      weatherData.city.innerHTML = cityName;
      weatherData.weather.innerHTML =  ", " + weatherDescription;
      weatherData.temperature.innerHTML = weatherTemperature + weatherData.units;
    }, false);

    xhr.addEventListener("error", function(err){
      alert("Could not complete the request");
    }, false);

    xhr.open("GET", "https://fourtonfish.com/tutorials/weather-web-app/getlocationandweather.php?owapikey=e2db5b0453a25a492e87ad8b03046a7c&units=metric", true);
    xhr.send();
  }
  else{
    alert("Unable to fetch the location and weather data.");
  }           
}


function loadBackground(lat, lon, weatherTag) {
  var script_element = document.createElement('script');

  script_element.src = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=1452866c8cea54acd0075022ef573a07&lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&accuracy=1&tags=" + weatherTag + "&sort=relevance&extras=url_l&format=json";
  
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script_element);
}

function jsonFlickrApi(data){
  if (data.photos.pages > 0){
    //var randomPhotoId = parseInt(data.photos.total);
    var photo = data.photos.photo[Math.floor(Math.random()*parseInt(data.photos.photo.length))];
    document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + photo.url_l + "')";
    document.querySelector("#image-source").setAttribute("href", "http://www.flickr.com/photos/" + photo.owner + "/" + photo.id);
  }
  else{
    document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://fourtonfish.com/tutorials/weather-web-app/images/default.jpg')";
    document.querySelector("#image-source").setAttribute("href", "https://www.flickr.com/photos/superfamous/310185523/sizes/o/");
  }
}

function translateDescription(description) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=pt&dt=t&q=" + description, false);
    xhttp.send();
    var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    return response[0][0][0];
}

getLocationAndWeather();
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  color: #fff;
  background: #888;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

section {

   min-height: 100%;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0 0.3em;
  line-height: 1em;
  
}

p {
  padding: 0 1em;
}

a{
  color: #fff;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

#temperature {
   text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 0.05em dotted white;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1 id= "city">Weather Web App</h1>
  <p> <a id="temperature" href="#" onclick="switchUnits(); return false;" title ="Click to switch between metric and imperial units"></a><span id = "weather"> by Shazam (tutorial from @fourtonfish)</p>
</section>

<footer>
  <p>Powered by <a href="http://flickr.com/services/api/">Flickr</a> and <a href="http://openweathermap.org">Openweathermap.org</a>.
    
  Created by <a href="https://twitter.com/steelcitycoach">@steelcitycoach</a>. <a id="image-source" href="#">Image source</a>.</p>
  
</footer>
```

This is the PHP file that make the connection to the API.

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST["owapikey"]) && isset($_REQUEST["units"])){
     
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $owapikey = $_REQUEST['owapikey'];
        $units = $_REQUEST['units'];
     
    //  $request = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json/{$ip}"));
     
        $latitude = $request->latitude;
        $longitude = $request->longitude;
     
        $request = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ip-api.com/json/{$ip}"));
        $latitude = $request->lat;
        $longitude = $request->lon;
     
        $request = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={$latitude}&lon={$longitude}&units={$units}&APPID={$owapikey}"));
     
        $weather = array(
            "latitude" => $latitude,
            "longitude" => $longitude,
            "city" => $request->name,
            "weather" => array(
                "simple" => $request->weather[0]->main,
                "description" => $request->weather[0]->description,
                "temperature" => $request->main->temp
            ),
            "source" => "smart-ip.net, openweathermap.org"
        );
     
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($weather);
    }
    else{
        echo "<!doctype html><html><head><style>body{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;}</style></head><body><h1>Hello</h1><p>This is a wrapper service for <a href='http://smart-ip.net/'>smart-ip.net</a> and <a href='http://openweathermap.org/'>openweathermap.org</a> that I made for a <a href='https://fourtonfish.makes.org/thimble/make-your-own-web-mashup'>tutorial on web mashups</a>.</p><p><a href='http://fourtonfish.com/'>Back to the main page.</a></body></html>";
    }
    ?>
```

This exemplifies my objective:

a) the weather is nice and there is no clouds - go off for a walk!

B) the weather is heavy and rainy - stay at home!

I'm learning PHP, know a little JavaScript and too little about JSON. How can I do this variation, and which file? (On the API link PHP or the index, for example). I imagine that I could do something like this, but it doesn't work...

```
if ($resultado1 == 'clear sky') { echo "Resposta 1"; 
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What doesn't work? What does work?

Comment: What work: It shows the temperature and the description. What doesn't work: use that responses (clear sky, few clouds, etc) to create variable response texts to appear on the screen. I will try to be more objective on my answer, sorry for that.